# SQL query composition search

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find a composition of data stored in a database to fullfill a input value using sql.

Table first

```
 ID| Value |
 1 | 8     |
 2 | 10    |
 3 | 12    |
 4 | 14    |
```

Table values

```
 ID| Value |
 1 | 2     |
 2 | 3     |
 3 | 4     |
 4 | 5     |
 5 | 6     |
```

If the input value is 8, i have to find possible compositions of the values in the table that equals this.

The possibilities:

```
ID, 1 and 5
ID, 3 and 3
ID, 2 and 4
```

how do i get this from an sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for pairs, you do a join with a condition:

```
select t1.Value, t2.Value
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.Value + t2.Value = 8;
```

EDIT:

If you actually want to get 1 and 5 but not 5 and 1, then you need to use distinct and another condition in the `on` clause:

```
select distinct t1.Value, t2.Value
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.Value + t2.Value = 8 and
        t1.Id <= t2.Id;
```

The `distinct` is so "3, 3" doesn't appear twice.

Comment: thanks, answers the question.. i have just edited something, can you maybe help me out here. Also it should be the value from the same table?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a self-`CROSS JOIN` and check against the total. The `<=` condition is to prevent duplicates arising from the recipical:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID
FROM tbl t1 CROSS JOIN tbl t2
WHERE t1.value + t2.value = 8
AND t1.ID <= t2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.ID,T2.ID as ID2
FROM TableName T1 CROSS JOIN
     TableName T2
WHERE T1.Value+T2.Value=8 AND T1.ID<=T2.ID
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

Result:

```
ID  ID2
1   5
2   4
3   3
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cdd7e/11).